# Type hinting the return value of a class method that returns self?

Tags: python, python-typing

as the questions describes, I wanna type hint a `self` return , something like:

```
class A:
    def foo(self) -> [what goes here?]:
        # do something
        return self
```

Things I already tried:

1. annotating it as `A` ( adding `from __future__ import annotations` at the top ): this means the method returns an instantiated `A()` object, not necessarily `self`.
2. annotating it as `Type[A]` ( adding `from typing import Type` ): this means the method is returning is returning an un-instantiated `A`, which isnt remotely close to `self`.
3. annotating is as `Self` ( adding `from typing_extensions import Self` ): mypy gives an error:
   `Variable "typing_extensions.Self" is not valid as a type  [valid-type]mypy(error)`

**Things that might be of help**: hovering over the method `foo` with no annotations of a return value, `VScode` hints shows - `Self@A`, i dont understand it but, this definitely differentiates between returning another instantiated class `A()` and returning `self` ... Thanks

Comment: My best guess is you can't really do this in python -- you would require a value-dependent type that allows you to distinguish between different instances of a single simply typed object A, something that python's typing ecosystem does not support.

Comment: To add to that. The purpose of type hinting is to specify type, not instance. So what you want is probably not possible. Python 3.11 will have a `Self` type but in this particular example (without inheritance) it does the same as just specifying `A`, i.e. allowing all instances of that type. https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/

Answer (score 8):

I can't find any question that covers this closely, so will try to explain.

### What does "same type" mean for type checking

Well, probably this is the long form of "you can't, and you shouldn't".

Type checking aims to confirm that all functions are called with proper argument types and return expected types. I suggest to read [PEP483](https://peps.python.org/pep-0483/) first to understand concept of *type* better. Suppose you have the following:

```py
s1 = ''.join(['a', 'b', 'c'])
s2 = ''.join(['a', 'b', 'c'])
assert s1 is not s2
assert s1 == s2
```

(`join` to avoid optimization, but it's another story). Are they the same object? No, `is not` clearly states this (they have different memory addresses). But will `s2` be acceptable whenever you want `s1`? Definitely yes. You will not create a function that operates only on `s1` and checks this fact with `is`, right?

Now what is the **difference** between `self` as reference to exact object and `self` as any `A` instance? When we talk about type checking, all `A` instances are completely equivalent and indistinguishable. They have the same set of methods and attributes (including types). We can ask: "which type errors can be introduced or removed, if we explicitly declare object to be `self` instance and not just `self` type?" I really cannot think of any. If you want this for semantics, use docstring - types should not be abused for everything. `self` object is absolutely the same as any other `A()` instance for type checker.

### Simple solution: return class instance

Your first code sample is almost fine. Annotate return as `A` to tell that it returns instance of class `A`, it will work for final class:

```py
class A:
    def foo(self) -> A:
        return self
```

However, this approach has a drawback (it is good explained in PEP673 about `Self` type):

```py
class AChild(A):
    pass

# mypy
reveal_type(AChild().foo())  # N: revealed type is "__main__.A"
```

If you create new `A` in `foo` and return it, then this approach is perfect. If you `return self` - it is valid, but not precise. That's why we need `Self` type.

### `Self` type

`Self` type was introduced in [PEP673](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/), and was not supported by `mypy` at the time of writing this. (update: supported since [`mypy 1.0`](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#mypy-10) released on Feb. 6, 2023) Your usage in 3rd example was perfectly valid and will work after implementation in type checkers (see 5-th code block in "Motivation" section of PEP). The support was added to `mypy` in version `1.0`, so if you're using this version or later - this section is the proper answer.

Here's how you can use `Self` (assuming `python=3.11` not to bother with `typing_extensions`):

```py
from typing import Self

class A:
    def foo(self) -> Self:
        return self

class AChild(A):
    pass

# mypy
reveal_type(AChild().foo())  # N: revealed type is "__main__.AChild"
reveal_type(A().foo())  # N: revealed type is "__main__.A"
```

### Implementing `Self` type without using it

However, you can mimic `Self` accurately with a few lines of code (and `python >= 3.7`, AFAIR).

```py
from typing import TypeVar

_Self = TypeVar('_Self', bound='A')

class A:
    def foo(self: _Self) -> _Self:
        return self

class AChild(A):
    pass

# mypy
reveal_type(AChild().foo())  # N: revealed type is "__main__.AChild"
reveal_type(A().foo())  # N: revealed type is "__main__.A"
```

Now this works. All subclasses will return their class instance.

Comment: the linked mypy ticket is now closed

Comment: @joel it is, but nor released (will be with version 1.0, so is available only on master now)

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to put the class name in the quotation: e.g:

```
class A:
  def foo(self) -> 'A':
    # do something
    return self
```

In IDE(e.g. Pycharm) you can navigate to the class by ctl(or cmd in macos) and click 'A'.

Comment: I think you might be a little late...