# package in python 'typing'

Tags: python, package, python-typing, typing

```
from typing import Self
```

ImportError of this code is: cannot import name 'Self' from 'typing'.

I had download a typing package in my pycharm, but didn't succeed. What should I do?

Comment: you shouldn't need to download the `typing` package, it's part of the standard library. I don't know what you downloaded. Your problem is almost certainly that your python version doesn't have `Self` in `typing`. It might be in `typing_extensions`. If not, either use a newer python version or try the last bit of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72182814/5986907

Comment: `typing.Self` only landed in python 3.11 through [PEP673](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/), please check `python --version`.